# automake automatic dependencies custom language/scripts

Tags: automake

I have a bit of file processing to do in Automake and can't figure out how to do it correctly (using either automake rules of gnu make extensions). For example, I have a file called **refName.in** and wish to produce the output **refName.out**.  I have two relevant command-lines:

```
produce-out refName.in refName.out
produce-deps refName.in
```

The first simply takes the input file and produces the output. The second provides a list of dependencies for the file.

What am I supposed to do in Automake to get this setup working? I wish to have full dependency tracking, such that if any file in the list produced by *produce-deps* will trigger *produce-out* to be called.

*(NOTE: I have no problem changing how these commands work. One command can produce the output and dependencies if needed. Different command-line switches, etc. can also be modified.)*

*(PS: If need be a GNU make extension is totally okay. I already use patterned rules in the Makefile.am and other extensions.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only automake specific thing you need for this is to add the built file to [`BUILT_SOURCES`](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Built-Sources-Example.html):

```
BUILT_SOURCES := refName.out

# You might well want refName.in in EXTRA_DIST
EXTRA_DIST := refName.in

# then any standard Make rules will do:
refName.out: refName.in $(shell produce-deps refName.in)
        produce-out refName.in refName.out
```

If you want a more sophisticated way of doing the dependencies you can use these rules with GNU make's [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Include.html), which will only cause produce-deps to be run when refName.deps is missing or refName.in changes:

```
refName.deps: refName.in
        echo 'ref-deps := "' $(shell produce-deps refName.in) '"' > refName.deps

include refName.deps

refName.out: refName.in $(ref-deps)
        produce-out refName.in refName.out
```

You can [make these rules generic](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Automatic-Prerequisites.html#Automatic-Prerequisites) with the usual GNU make `%` rules.

Comment: I'm not clear on how to do the gnu makefile bits either for the automatically generated dependencies.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y - I made an edit that shows a crude way of adding the extra dependencies by calling `produce-deps`. It'll call this every time your run make, but it's simple safe and clean.